# View real-time information - Run Symfony command

Tags: php, symfony, command

I've create a Symfony command to import records in database

[image]

And now I'm trying to create an HMI for that, but when I click on button to execute command, the browser load until the end of the order, **but I would like to have the terminal information in real time**

*My code*

```
public function importActesAddUpdateAction(Request $request)
{
    //Set max execution time
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600); //1H

    $kernel = $this->get('kernel');

    //Get path of project dir
    $projectDir = $this->get('kernel')->getProjectDir();
    $destination = $projectDir . "/data";

    $application = new Application($kernel);
    $application->setAutoExit(false);

    $input = new ArrayInput(array(
       'command' => 'csv:import',
       //InputArgument
       'path' => $destination, //To directory data
       // InputOption
       '--add-update' => null,
    ));

    //Configure output
    $output = new BufferedOutput(
        OutputInterface::VERBOSITY_DEBUG,
        true // true for decorated
    );

    //Run command
    $application->run($input, $output);

    // return the output
    $converter = new AnsiToHtmlConverter();
    $content = $output->fetch();

    return new Response($converter->convert($content));
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: What is a "HMI"?

Comment: In France it's 'IHM' for Interface Homme Machine = user interface

Comment: Might consider using processes, which handle real time outputs : http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

Comment: I've try with process (call method to execute in ajax), but my server crash with this mistake: Command "server:run" exited with code "1" {"command":"server:run","code":1} but why ?

Comment: Check [Streaming console command output from symfony controller](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/stkb/streaming-console-command-output-from-symfony-controller) and [Streaming symfony response from twig template with XMLHttpRequest](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/canq/streaming-symfony-response-from-twig-template-with-xmlhttprequest) to see if they help you at all.

Comment: From what I know, this is not possible to have a realtime output when launching a command from a controller. When I need the output of the command I am running in a controller, I just send the output when the execution has finished. BTW, IHM in english is GUI (litterally it's HUD but GUI matches better here)